# How to generate dynamic DNS entries in AWS Route 53 using Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-cloud

I have a domain *my-domain.com* with a Hosted Zone in Route 53. I´m using the same code in GitLab for different workspaces using Terraform Cloud to deploy different environments. The code is the same in all the branches but Terraform use *main* branch for Production deployments, *dev* branch for Development deployments and *demo* branch for Demo deployments, is the same code, each branch linked to a particular workspace and each workspace with particular environment variables. How I can create an aws_route53_record resource able to work dinamically with each environment?

Answer (score 0):

This example allow me to deploy ui.mydomain.com for production environment, ui-dev.mydomain.com for dev environment, all the time checking the value of the  *environment* variable:

```
    data "aws_route53_zone" "mydomain-public" {
      name         = "mydomain.com."
      private_zone = false
    }
    
    resource "aws_route53_record" "ui-app-dns" {
      zone_id = data.aws_route53_zone.mydomain-public.zone_id
      name    = var.environment == "prod" ? "ui" : format("ui-%s", var.environment)
      type    = "CNAME"
      ttl     = "300"
      records = [aws_cloudfront_distribution.ui-app-cloudfront.domain_name]
    }
```

The key is the line

> name    = var.environment == "prod" ? "ui" : format("ui-%s",
> var.environment)

This line check the value, if is *prod* the name to use is **ui**, else something like **ui-*value*** (ui-demo/ui-dev)